# Still possible to restore boot partition? (QQZM N5063 Ipcam)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I know now that I should not touch the boot partition.
I understand now that it was just that I rebuild a rootfs but it's a little late.
I wonder if I still can restore the boot partition with the backup.

If you have information to give me I would be happy because at the moment my feet in concrete.
I started working with Buildroot to rebuild a kernel and rootfs but I'd rather just rebuild the rootfs because I will certainly be very annoyed with drivers and kernel configuration.
I have no information about the original compilation options.

In short, you have understood my ambarras.
So if you have ideas or research directions I am listening to you.

Thank you

---

When I had my hand on the system I made a backup with the DD command:

```
dd if=/dev/mtdblock1 of=/mnt/nfs/mtdblock1 bs=65536
```

Backup file:

```
binwalk mtdblock1
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x853F419E, created: 2014-07-22 02:45:04, image size: 2890840 bytes, Data Address: 0x80008000, Entry Point: 0x80008000, data CRC: 0xB24E77CA, OS: Linux, CPU: ARM, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: "Linux-3.0.8"
22608         0x5850          gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, NULL date:
```

Later, I wanted to restore the partition with the following commands:

```
set ipaddr 10.10.10.3
set serverip 10.10.10.9
sf probe 0
sf erase 0x100000 0x300000
tftp mtdblock1
sf write 0x80008000 0x100000 0x30000
```

Now my webcam loop on the kernel boot:

```
U-Boot 2010.06 (Jul 29 2014 - 18:28:01)

Check spi flash controller v350... Found
Spi(cs1) ID: 0xEF 0x40 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00
Spi(cs1): Block:64KB Chip:16MB Name:"W25Q128B"
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3 \0x08\0x08\0x08 2 \0x08\0x08\0x08 1 \0x08\0x08\0x08 0 
16384 KiB hi_sfc at 0:0 is now current device<code>

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
Image Name:   Linux-3.0.8
Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
Data Size:    2890840 Bytes = 2.8 MiB
Load Address: 80008000
Entry Point:  80008000
Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

data abort
pc : [<80008af8>]\0x09   lr : [<80007fff>]
sp : 802cac50  ip : 0000001c\0x09 fp : 802cac6c
r10: 80007fff  r9 : ffffffff\0x09 r8 : 80000100
r7 : 00001f40  r6 : 80007fff\0x09 r5 : 80007fff  r4 : 802c9c28
r3 : 00001f40  r2 : 802dac70\0x09 r1 : 802cac70  r0 : 80008000
Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs off  Mode SVC_32
Resetting CPU ...

resetting ...
```

Here is some information on the webcam:

```
hisilicon # printenv
bootdelay=3
baudrate=115200
ethaddr=00:00:23:34:45:66
ipaddr=192.168.1.10
serverip=192.168.1.2
netmask=255.255.255.0
bootfile="uImage"
bootcmd=sf probe 0;sf read 0x82000000 0x100000 0x300000;bootm 0x82000000
bootargs=mem=64M console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=jffs2 mtdparts=hi_sfc:1M(boot),3M(kernel),12M(rootfs)
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
stderr=serial
verify=n
ver=U-Boot 2010.06 (Jul 29 2014 - 18:28:01)

Environment size: 427/262140 bytes

# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00100000 00010000 "boot"
mtd1: 00300000 00010000 "kernel"
mtd2: 00c00000 00010000 "rootfs"

# cat /proc/cpuinfo 
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 218.72
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : hi3518
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

Comment: Go to the vendors web sight and look for firmware downloads.  Even if they are not in the proper format, you can probably find the raw binary some where in the image.  Alternatively, find someone else with the hardware and use `nanddump` and `nandwrite` on the */dev/mtdX* devices.  You should never use *mtdblockX*, they are garbage.

Comment: Look for 'erase blocks' that are largely 0xff in your existing image.  Try to remove those portions.  *mtdblockX* does not handle bad blocks and will dump them as is.  I find this a path to madness, but you might be able to do it.  Getting the image by the ways above is better.

Answer (score 0):

The start before restoration:

```
U-Boot 2010.06 (Jul 29 2014 - 18:28:01)

Check spi flash controller v350... Found
Spi(cs1) ID: 0xEF 0x40 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00
Spi(cs1): Block:64KB Chip:16MB Name:"W25Q128B"
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  1 \0x08\0x08\0x08 0 
16384 KiB hi_sfc at 0:0 is now current device

## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.0.8
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    2890840 Bytes = 2.8 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
OK

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
Linux version 3.0.8 (cwen@ubuntu) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Hisilicon_v100(gcc4.4-290+uclibc_0.9.32.1+eabi+linuxpthread)) ) #1 Tue Jul 22 10:45:00 HKT 2014
CPU: ARM926EJ-S [41069265] revision 5 (ARMv5TEJ), cr=00053177
CPU: VIVT data cache, VIVT instruction cache
Machine: hi3518
Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
AXI bus clock 200000000.
Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 16256
Kernel command line: mem=64M console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock2 rootfstype=jffs2 mtdparts=hi_sfc:1M(boot),3M(kernel),12M(rootfs)
PID hash table entries: 256 (order: -2, 1024 bytes)
Dentry cache hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
Inode-cache hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
Memory: 64MB = 64MB total
Memory: 59472k/59472k available, 6064k reserved, 0K highmem
Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xfff00000 - 0xfffe0000   ( 896 kB)
    DMA     : 0xffc00000 - 0xffe00000   (   2 MB)
    vmalloc : 0xc4800000 - 0xfe000000   ( 920 MB)
    lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xc4000000   (  64 MB)
    modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
      .init : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0029000   ( 132 kB)
      .text : 0xc0029000 - 0xc0513000   (5032 kB)
      .data : 0xc0514000 - 0xc0537fa0   ( 144 kB)
       .bss : 0xc0537fc4 - 0xc0555240   ( 117 kB)
SLUB: Genslabs=13, HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
NR_IRQS:32 nr_irqs:32 32
sched_clock: 32 bits at 100MHz, resolution 10ns, wraps every 42949ms
Console: colour dummy device 80x30
Calibrating delay loop... 218.72 BogoMIPS (lpj=1093632)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
NET: Registered protocol family 16
Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
uart:0: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20080000 (irq = 5) is a PL011 rev2
console [ttyAMA0] enabled
uart:1: ttyAMA1 at MMIO 0x20090000 (irq = 5) is a PL011 rev2
bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
SCSI subsystem initialized
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Switching to clocksource timer1
NET: Registered protocol family 2
IP route cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
TCP reno registered
UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
NET: Registered protocol family 1
RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
RPC: Registered udp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
NetWinder Floating Point Emulator V0.97 (double precision)
VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
JFFS2 version 2.2. (NAND) \0xc2\0xa9 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
fuse init (API version 7.16)
msgmni has been set to 116
Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 253)
io scheduler noop registered
io scheduler deadline registered (default)
io scheduler cfq registered
brd: module loaded
loop: module loaded
Spi id table Version 1.22
Spi(cs1) ID: 0xEF 0x40 0x18 0x00 0x00 0x00
SPI FLASH start_up_mode is 3 Bytes
Spi(cs1): 
Block:64KB 
Chip:16MB 
Name:"W25Q128B"
spi size: 16MB
chip num: 1
3 cmdlinepart partitions found on MTD device hi_sfc
Creating 3 MTD partitions on "hi_sfc":
0x000000000000-0x000000100000 : "boot"
0x000000100000-0x000000400000 : "kernel"
0x000000400000-0x000001000000 : "rootfs"
Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
himii: probed
usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2500usb
usbcore: registered new interface driver rt73usb
ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
hiusb-ehci hiusb-ehci.0: HIUSB EHCI
hiusb-ehci hiusb-ehci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
hiusb-ehci hiusb-ehci.0: irq 15, io mem 0x100b0000
hiusb-ehci hiusb-ehci.0: USB 0.0 started, EHCI 1.00
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
hiusb-ohci hiusb-ohci.0: HIUSB OHCI
hiusb-ohci hiusb-ohci.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
hiusb-ohci hiusb-ohci.0: irq 16, io mem 0x100a0000
hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-alauda
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-datafab
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-freecom
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-isd200
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-jumpshot
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-sddr09
usbcore: registered new interface driver ums-sddr55
usbcore: registered new interface driver mdc800
mdc800: v0.7.5 (30/10/2000):USB Driver for Mustek MDC800 Digital Camera
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver
TCP cubic registered
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
NET: Registered protocol family 10
NET: Registered protocol family 17
NET: Registered protocol family 15
lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
Registering the dns_resolver key type
registered taskstats version 1
drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
\0xf8usb 1-1: new high speed USB device number 2 using hiusb-ehci
VFS: Mounted root (jffs2 filesystem) on device 31:2.
Freeing init memory: 132K
mmc0: new SDHC card at address 0002
mmcblk0: mmc0:0002 N/A   3.75 GiB 
 mmcblk0: p1

            _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
            \  _  _   _  _ _ ___
            / /__/ \ |_/
           / __   /  -  _ ___
          / /  / /  / /
  _ _ _ _/ /  /  \_/  \_ ______
___________\___\__________________

[RCS]: /etc/init.d/S00devs
[RCS]: /etc/init.d/S01udev
udevd (510): /proc/510/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/510/oom_score_adj instead.
[RCS]: /etc/init.d/S80network
[RCS]: /etc/init.d/S90zm
tar: can't open '/qqzm/param/rootfs.tar.gz': No such file or directory
Hisilicon Media Memory Zone Manager
hi3518_base: module license 'Proprietary' taints kernel.
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Hisilicon UMAP device driver interface: v3.00
pa:84000000, va:c4a00000
load sys.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load viu.ko for Hi3518...OK!
ISP Mod init!
load vpss.ko ....OK!
load vou.ko ....OK!
load venc.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load group.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load chnl.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load h264e.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load jpege.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load rc.ko for Hi3518...OK!
load region.ko ....OK!
load vda.ko ....OK!
hi_i2c init is ok!
Kernel: ssp initial ok!
acodec inited!
insert audio
==== Your input Sensor type is ov9712 ====
************[Load Hi3518c]**************
*** Board tools : ver0.0.1_20121120 *** 
[debug]: {source/utils/cmdshell.c:166}cmdstr:himm
0x200f0138: 0x00000001 --> 0x00000000 
[END]
*** Board tools : ver0.0.1_20121120 *** 
[debug]: {source/utils/cmdshell.c:166}cmdstr:himm
0x20140400: 0x00000020 --> 0x00000040 
[END]
*** Board tools : ver0.0.1_20121120 *** 
[debug]: {source/utils/cmdshell.c:166}cmdstr:himm
0x20140100: 0x00000000 --> 0x00000040 
[END]
\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [main                 0052] pri: >>>>>>>>>> Start Running zmupdate... <<<<<<<<<<
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [main                 0053] pri: >>>>>>-------- zmupdate Version: 1.1.0 --------<<<<<<
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [zm_set_up_flag       0064] pri: zm_set_up_flag : UPDATE_ENABLE
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [main                 0068] pri: create thread server update OK!
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [main                 0075] pri: create thread client update OK!
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [server_thread_update 0086] pri: accepting connections...
\0x1b[m\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [client_thread_update 0428] pri: Waiting [ 3600 ] Seconds To Start zmupdate...
>>>enter STAT_MACH_INIT status ...
\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [update_connect_tcp.ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
. 0178] pri: server addr:10.10.10.6,port:8080
\0x1b[1;31m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [update_connect_tcp.. 0200] err: connect server[10.10.10.6:0x1f90] error:Network is unreachable
\0x1b[m\0x1b[1;31m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [main                 0783] err: connect upgrade server error!
\0x1b[m\0x1b[m>>>enter STAT_MACH_CHECK status ...
\0x1b[0;32;32m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [update_connect_tcp.. 0178] pri: server addr:p1.zmvideo.net,port:8080
\0x1b[1;31m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [update_connect_tcp.. 0185] err: getaddrinfo[p1.zmvideo.net:8080] error:Network is unreachable
\0x1b[m\0x1b[1;31m[1970-01-01 00:00:07] [check_update_status  0541] err: connect upgrade server error!
\0x1b[m\0x1b[m>>>enter STAT_MACH_RECV status ...
the wifi conf is exist
rmmod: can't unload 'mt7601Usta': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
rtusb init rt2870 --->
usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2870
\0x1b[1;36m\0x09\0x1b[0;35m/\0x1b[1;35m/\0x1b[0;33m=\0x1b[1;33m=\0x1b[0;37m=\0x1b[1;37m=\0x1b[0;32;31m=\0x1b[1;31m=\0x1b[0;32;32m=\0x1b[1;32m=\0x1b[0;32;34m=\0x1b[1;34m=\0x1b[1;30m=\0x1b[0;36m=\0x1b[1;36m=\0x1b[0;35m=\0x1b[1;35m=\0x1b[0;33m=\0x1b[1;33m=\0x1b[0;37m=\0x1b[1;37m=\0x1b[0;32;31m=\0x1b[1;31m \0x1b[0;32;32mW\0x1b[1;32me\0x1b[0;32;34ml\0x1b[1;34mc\0x1b[1;30mo\0x1b[0;36mm\0x1b[1;36me\0x1b[0;35m \0x1b[1;35mt\0x1b[0;33mo\0x1b[1;33m \0x1b[0;37mQ\0x1b[1;37mQ\0x1b[0;32;31mZ\0x1b[1;31mM\0x1b[0;32;32m \0x1b[1;32mp\0x1b[0;32;34mr\0x1b[1;34mo\0x1b[1;30md\0x1b[0;36mu\0x1b[1;36mc\0x1b[0;35mt\0x1b[1;35m \0x1b[0;33m=\0x1b[1;33m=\0x1b[0;37m=\0x1b[1;37m=\0x1b[0;32;31m=\0x1b[1;31m=\0x1b[0;32;32m=\0x1b[1;32m=\0x1b[0;32;34m=\0x1b[1;34m=\0x1b[1;30m=\0x1b[0;36m=\0x1b[1;36m=\0x1b[0;35m=\0x1b[1;35m=\0x1b[0;33m=\0x1b[1;33m/\0x1b[0;37m/\0x1b[1;37m
\0x09\0x09\0x1b[1;36msoftware_version: orange_sun_basic_c004_1.0.9
\0x09\0x09hardware_version: hi3518c_sun_1.0
PHY: himii:01 - Link is Up - 100/Full
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
RtmpOSNetDevDetach(): RtmpOSNetDeviceDetach(), dev->name=ra0!
0x1300 = ffffffff
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address c499e01c
pgd = c2fa4000
[c499e01c] *pgd=83821811, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
Internal error: Oops: 7 [#1]
Modules linked in: mt7601Usta hi3518_adec(P) hi3518_aenc(P) hi3518_ao(P) hi3518_ai(P) hi3518_sio(P) hidmac acodec(P) ssp_ad9020 pwm hi_i2c hi3518_ive(P) hi3518_vda(P) hi3518_region(P) hi3518_rc(P) hi3518_jpege(P) hi3518_h264e(P) hi3518_chnl(P) hi3518_group(P) hi3518_venc(P) hifb(P) hi3518_vou(P) hi3518_vpss(P) hi3518_isp(P) hi3518_viu(P) hi3518_dsu(P) hi3518_tde(P) hiuser hi3518_sys(P) hi3518_base(P) mmz
CPU: 0    Tainted: P             (3.0.8 #1)
PC is at __dev_set_rx_mode+0x2c/0xa0
LR is at dev_set_rx_mode+0x1c/0x24
pc : [<c02e2214>]    lr : [<c02e25a0>]    psr: 20000013
sp : c2ed3da0  ip : c2ed3dc0  fp : c2ed3dbc
r10: c2d1ab00  r9 : c2d1ab00  r8 : c054e580
r7 : 00000001  r6 : 00001002  r5 : c499e000  r4 : c2f9c400
r3 : 00001003  r2 : 00000200  r1 : 00000003  r0 : c2f9c400
Flags: nzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
Control: 0005317f  Table: 82fa4000  DAC: 00000015

PC: 0xc02e2194:
2194  e89da878 e2655000 e5845148 e1a01004 e59f002c eb048717 e3e0004a e89da878
21b4  e59f1020 e59f2020 e59f0020 eb048711 eb0486a5 eaffffd6 c04e9844 c04e984c
21d4  c04e9854 c04e97d8 c04e9520 00001104 c04e941c e1a0c00d e92dd878 e24cb004
21f4  e59030ec e1a04000 e3130001 e59050e0 089da878 e5901044 e3110002 089da878
2214  e595301c e3530000 0a000001 e12fff33 e89da878 e5906134 e3560000 1a000008
2234  e590c144 e35c0000 1a00000d e5953020 e3530000 089da878 e1a00004 e12fff33
2254  e89da878 e5902144 e3520000 1afffff6 e3a01001 ebffffa5 e3a00001 e5840144
2274  eafffff1 e3e01000 ebffffa0 e5846144 eaffffed e1a0c00d e92dd878 e24cb004

LR: 0xc02e2520:
2520  e1a00004 e1a01005 ebffff56 e2506000 1a000008 e59430ec e3550000 13833b02
2540  03c33b02 e58430ec e1a01004 e3a00010 e3a02b02 eb0043d2 e1a00006 e89da878
2560  e59f1010 e59f2010 e59f0010 eb048626 eb0485ba eaffffe9 c04e9520 000010e7
2580  c04e941c e1a0c00d e92dd818 e24cb004 e1a04000 ebf59318 e1a00004 ebffff11
25a0  ebf59456 e89da818 e1a0c00d e92dd878 e24cb004 e1a04000 e1a05001 e59060ec
25c0  eb003b5d e3500000 0a00001d e594114c e59430ec e0852001 e3833c02 e3520000
25e0  e58430ec e584214c 1a000003 e3550000 b3c33c02 b58430ec aa00000a e1a06806
2600  e1530826 03a00000 089da878 e3a01c02 e1a00004 ebfff6f6 e1a00004 ebffffd8

SP: 0xc2ed3d20:
3d20  bf315464 bf2eac94 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 ffffffff c2ed3d8c
3d40  00001002 00000001 c2ed3dbc c2ed3d58 c002feec c0029280 c2f9c400 00000003
3d60  00000200 00001003 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 00000001 c054e580 c2d1ab00
3d80  c2d1ab00 c2ed3dbc c2ed3dc0 c2ed3da0 c02e25a0 c02e2214 20000013 ffffffff
3da0  c2ed2000 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 c2ed3dd4 c2ed3dc0 c02e25a0 c02e21f8
3dc0  c32894c0 c2f9c400 c2ed3dec c2ed3dd8 c02e5388 c02e2594 c2f9c400 00001043
3de0  c2ed3e0c c2ed3df0 c02e2720 c02e52c4 c2f9c400 00001002 c2ed3e60 00008914
3e00  c2ed3e2c c2ed3e10 c02e527c c02e26bc 00000014 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e60

IP: 0xc2ed3d40:
3d40  00001002 00000001 c2ed3dbc c2ed3d58 c002feec c0029280 c2f9c400 00000003
3d60  00000200 00001003 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 00000001 c054e580 c2d1ab00
3d80  c2d1ab00 c2ed3dbc c2ed3dc0 c2ed3da0 c02e25a0 c02e2214 20000013 ffffffff
3da0  c2ed2000 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 c2ed3dd4 c2ed3dc0 c02e25a0 c02e21f8
3dc0  c32894c0 c2f9c400 c2ed3dec c2ed3dd8 c02e5388 c02e2594 c2f9c400 00001043
3de0  c2ed3e0c c2ed3df0 c02e2720 c02e52c4 c2f9c400 00001002 c2ed3e60 00008914
3e00  c2ed3e2c c2ed3e10 c02e527c c02e26bc 00000014 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e60
3e20  c2ed3ebc c2ed3e30 c0333fe4 c02e5274 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e78 bea60be0

FP: 0xc2ed3d3c:
3d3c  c2ed3d8c 00001002 00000001 c2ed3dbc c2ed3d58 c002feec c0029280 c2f9c400
3d5c  00000003 00000200 00001003 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 00000001 c054e580
3d7c  c2d1ab00 c2d1ab00 c2ed3dbc c2ed3dc0 c2ed3da0 c02e25a0 c02e2214 20000013
3d9c  ffffffff c2ed2000 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 c2ed3dd4 c2ed3dc0 c02e25a0
3dbc  c02e21f8 c32894c0 c2f9c400 c2ed3dec c2ed3dd8 c02e5388 c02e2594 c2f9c400
3ddc  00001043 c2ed3e0c c2ed3df0 c02e2720 c02e52c4 c2f9c400 00001002 c2ed3e60
3dfc  00008914 c2ed3e2c c2ed3e10 c02e527c c02e26bc 00000014 c2ed2000 bea60be0
3e1c  c2ed3e60 c2ed3ebc c2ed3e30 c0333fe4 c02e5274 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e78

R0: 0xc2f9c380:
c380  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3a0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3c0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3e0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c400  00306172 00000064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c420  00000000 00000000 00000000 00200200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c440  00000000 00000003 c054e5c0 00200200 c2f9c450 c2f9c450 c2f9c458 c2f9c458
c460  00004000 40004800 00004800 00004020 00000003 00000003 00000000 00000000

R4: 0xc2f9c380:
c380  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3a0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3c0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c3e0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c400  00306172 00000064 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c420  00000000 00000000 00000000 00200200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
c440  00000000 00000003 c054e5c0 00200200 c2f9c450 c2f9c450 c2f9c458 c2f9c458
c460  00004000 40004800 00004800 00004020 00000003 00000003 00000000 00000000

R5: 0xc499df80:
df80  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
dfa0  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
dfc0  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
dfe0  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
e000  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
e020  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
e040  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********
e060  ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********

R8: 0xc054e500:
e500  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
e520  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
e540  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
e560  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
e580  00000001 00000001 c0531524 c0531524 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
e5a0  c3805cc0 c3805d20 c385d484 c31d79c4 c05378bc c04002e8 c3823c00 c3850600
e5c0  c381d848 c380c048 c381d000 c381d400 c385c124 c385c124 c381d800 c385d480
e5e0  00000080 00000000 c05d8418 c05d8454 c05d8490 c05d8588 c05d8680 c05d87c0

R9: 0xc2d1aa80:
aa80  00000004 00000000 c2d5c6bc 00000000 00000000 c0521b9c c2d4be5c 000002f9
aaa0  c051be4c 00000000 c05e04b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
aac0  ffdfe0c0 831ca0c0 00000000 c2d1aacc c2d1aacc ffdfd180 00000000 c398cadc
aae0  ffff8e68 00000001 00000000 00000300 00000000 00000000 c31ab400 00000001
ab00  c31fc8d8 c2457580 000001cd 000001cf 08c7d9a4 6475750a 646f6365 2c2c0065
ab20  00ffffff ff2ca8c0 72180000 64003061 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
ab40  c5400000 c56d4000 00000004 c2d4840d c2d48a0c c2d4878c c2d48b98 c2d48a98
ab60  00000023 0008003f c2d3df80 c49f9774 00000014 0008003f 00000381 c49f9788

R10: 0xc2d1aa80:
aa80  00000004 00000000 c2d5c6bc 00000000 00000000 c0521b9c c2d4be5c 000002f9
aaa0  c051be4c 00000000 c05e04b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
aac0  ffdfe0c0 831ca0c0 00000000 c2d1aacc c2d1aacc ffdfd180 00000000 c398cadc
aae0  ffff8e68 00000001 00000000 00000300 00000000 00000000 c31ab400 00000001
ab00  c31fc8d8 c2457580 000001cd 000001cf 08c7d9a4 6475750a 646f6365 2c2c0065
ab20  00ffffff ff2ca8c0 72180000 64003061 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
ab40  c5400000 c56d4000 00000004 c2d4840d c2d48a0c c2d4878c c2d48b98 c2d48a98
ab60  00000023 0008003f c2d3df80 c49f9774 00000014 0008003f 00000381 c49f9788
Process ifconfig (pid: 761, stack limit = 0xc2ed2270)
Stack: (0xc2ed3da0 to 0xc2ed4000)
3da0: c2ed2000 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 c2ed3dd4 c2ed3dc0 c02e25a0 c02e21f8
3dc0: c32894c0 c2f9c400 c2ed3dec c2ed3dd8 c02e5388 c02e2594 c2f9c400 00001043
3de0: c2ed3e0c c2ed3df0 c02e2720 c02e52c4 c2f9c400 00001002 c2ed3e60 00008914
3e00: c2ed3e2c c2ed3e10 c02e527c c02e26bc 00000014 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e60
3e20: c2ed3ebc c2ed3e30 c0333fe4 c02e5274 c2ed2000 bea60be0 c2ed3e78 bea60be0
3e40: 00000020 00000000 c2f9c400 c2ed3e70 c323c900 2c2ca8c0 00000014 00000000
3e60: 00306172 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001043 2c2ca8c0 000b11a0 000b1424
3e80: 00001043 2c2ca8c0 000b11a0 000b1424 000b11a0 00008914 bea60be0 c033521c
3ea0: 00000003 c00304c8 c2ed2000 00000000 c2ed3ecc c2ed3ec0 c03353d4 c03337f0
3ec0: c2ed3eec c2ed3ed0 c02d0da8 c033522c c02d0d34 bea60be0 c34c5180 00008914
3ee0: c2ed3f7c c2ed3ef0 c00b8098 c02d0d44 401e6674 c2ed3fb0 c2ed3fac c2ed3f08
3f00: c0029208 c00370dc 001cb000 c2f4f528 00100077 c32d4480 c2ed3f7c c2ed3f28
3f20: c0099f00 c0098a74 c2f4f9bc 00000000 00000000 000001cb 00000000 60000013
3f40: c2f4f9a0 c32d4480 001cc000 c32d44b4 001cb000 c3293f00 bea60be0 00008914
3f60: 00000003 c00304c8 c2ed2000 00000000 c2ed3fa4 c2ed3f80 c00b85e0 c00b8024
3f80: 40236144 00000000 bea60be0 00008914 00000003 00000036 00000000 c2ed3fa8
3fa0: c0030320 c00b85b0 bea60be0 00008914 00000003 00008914 bea60be0 00000000
3fc0: bea60be0 00008914 00000003 00000036 000b28c8 00000000 00000000 00000000
3fe0: 000d0118 bea60b98 0000e8c8 401afe70 60000010 00000003 00000000 00010074
Backtrace: 
[<c02e21e8>] (__dev_set_rx_mode+0x0/0xa0) from [<c02e25a0>] (dev_set_rx_mode+0x1c/0x24)
 r6:00001002 r5:c499e000 r4:c2f9c400 r3:c2ed2000
[<c02e2584>] (dev_set_rx_mode+0x0/0x24) from [<c02e5388>] (__dev_open+0xd4/0x108)
 r4:c2f9c400 r3:c32894c0
[<c02e52b4>] (__dev_open+0x0/0x108) from [<c02e2720>] (__dev_change_flags+0x74/0x12c)
 r5:00001043 r4:c2f9c400
[<c02e26ac>] (__dev_change_flags+0x0/0x12c) from [<c02e527c>] (dev_change_flags+0x18/0x50)
 r7:00008914 r6:c2ed3e60 r5:00001002 r4:c2f9c400
[<c02e5264>] (dev_change_flags+0x0/0x50) from [<c0333fe4>] (devinet_ioctl+0x804/0x8f0)
 r6:c2ed3e60 r5:bea60be0 r4:c2ed2000 r3:00000014
[<c03337e0>] (devinet_ioctl+0x0/0x8f0) from [<c03353d4>] (inet_ioctl+0x1b8/0x1c4)
[<c033521c>] (inet_ioctl+0x0/0x1c4) from [<c02d0da8>] (sock_ioctl+0x74/0x268)
[<c02d0d34>] (sock_ioctl+0x0/0x268) from [<c00b8098>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x58c)
 r6:00008914 r5:c34c5180 r4:bea60be0 r3:c02d0d34
[<c00b8014>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x0/0x58c) from [<c00b85e0>] (sys_ioctl+0x40/0x68)
[<c00b85a0>] (sys_ioctl+0x0/0x68) from [<c0030320>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
 r7:00000036 r6:00000003 r5:00008914 r4:bea60be0
Code: 089da878 e5901044 e3110002 089da878 (e595301c) 
---[ end trace d00c1c6a43f554d8 ]---
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Backtrace: 
[<c0033ff4>] (dump_backtrace+0x0/0x10c) from [<c0403c78>] (dump_stack+0x18/0x1c)
 r6:00000001 r5:c05382b0 r4:c05382b0 r3:0000000a
[<c0403c60>] (dump_stack+0x0/0x1c) from [<c0403ce0>] (panic+0x64/0x190)
[<c0403c7c>] (panic+0x0/0x190) from [<c0034384>] (die+0x248/0x2d4)
 r3:00000200 r2:00000200 r1:00000200 r0:c04b6abc
 r7:c2ed3c17
[<c003413c>] (die+0x0/0x2d4) from [<c0036e58>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x6c/0x8c)
[<c0036dec>] (__do_kernel_fault+0x0/0x8c) from [<c0036fb4>] (do_page_fault+0x13c/0x1e0)
 r8:c2ed3d58 r7:00000007 r6:c499e01c r5:c499e01c r4:c32d4480
r3:c2ed3d58
[<c0036e78>] (do_page_fault+0x0/0x1e0) from [<c00292ac>] (do_DataAbort+0x3c/0xa4)
[<c0029270>] (do_DataAbort+0x0/0xa4) from [<c002feec>] (__dabt_svc+0x4c/0x60)
Exception stack(0xc2ed3d58 to 0xc2ed3da0)
3d40:                                                       c2f9c400 00000003
3d60: 00000200 00001003 c2f9c400 c499e000 00001002 00000001 c054e580 c2d1ab00
3d80: c2d1ab00 c2ed3dbc c2ed3dc0 c2ed3da0 c02e25a0 c02e2214 20000013 ffffffff
 r7:00000001 r6:00001002 r5:c2ed3d8c r4:ffffffff
[<c02e21e8>] (__dev_set_rx_mode+0x0/0xa0) from [<c02e25a0>] (dev_set_rx_mode+0x1c/0x24)
 r6:00001002 r5:c499e000 r4:c2f9c400 r3:c2ed2000
[<c02e2584>] (dev_set_rx_mode+0x0/0x24) from [<c02e5388>] (__dev_open+0xd4/0x108)
 r4:c2f9c400 r3:c32894c0
[<c02e52b4>] (__dev_open+0x0/0x108) from [<c02e2720>] (__dev_change_flags+0x74/0x12c)
 r5:00001043 r4:c2f9c400
[<c02e26ac>] (__dev_change_flags+0x0/0x12c) from [<c02e527c>] (dev_change_flags+0x18/0x50)
 r7:00008914 r6:c2ed3e60 r5:00001002 r4:c2f9c400
[<c02e5264>] (dev_change_flags+0x0/0x50) from [<c0333fe4>] (devinet_ioctl+0x804/0x8f0)
 r6:c2ed3e60 r5:bea60be0 r4:c2ed2000 r3:00000014
[<c03337e0>] (devinet_ioctl+0x0/0x8f0) from [<c03353d4>] (inet_ioctl+0x1b8/0x1c4)
[<c033521c>] (inet_ioctl+0x0/0x1c4) from [<c02d0da8>] (sock_ioctl+0x74/0x268)
[<c02d0d34>] (sock_ioctl+0x0/0x268) from [<c00b8098>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x84/0x58c)
 r6:00008914 r5:c34c5180 r4:bea60be0 r3:c02d0d34
[<c00b8014>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x0/0x58c) from [<c00b85e0>] (sys_ioctl+0x40/0x68)
[<c00b85a0>] (sys_ioctl+0x0/0x68) from [<c0030320>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x2c)
 r7:00000036 r6:00000003 r5:00008914 r4:bea60be0
```

Answer (score 0):

thank again

I abandoned the restoration of the boot partition.
I found uImage from the SDK, perfect restoration :))

I tried to restore rootfs got a message saying that the file system does not have the correct version :(

So I am left with the SDK's rootfs and it works well :))

I got a few binaries of the original rootfs but when I run I have this:

```
btools: symbol '_h_errno': can't resolve symbol
btools: symbol '_h_errno': can't resolve symbol
btools: symbol '_errno': can't resolve symbol
btools: symbol '_errno': can't resolve symbol
```

I think it is because of the configuration of original kernel that I do not possess.
Do you believe that there is a solution?